# Не против, если

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нормально ли так сказать

> *Вы не против, если я сяду?*

Ведь вроде бы это уже прижилось в языке, и не обязательно говорить

> *Вы не против того, чтоб я сел?*

Так даже чудно́ звучит как-то. Не так ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фраза нормальная, не буду Людмилу повторять.

А вот в отношении того, что там дама себе подумала...
Тут есть минимум два варианта объяснения. Или она вообще не из культурных и просто не привыкла к вежливости подобного рода. Но это вещи этикетные, к языку имеющие весьма косвенное отношение.

Либо, что более вероятно, ей слово "сел"/"сяду" ухо не приласкало. Ну вы знаете, есть такая у шибко грамотных манера полагать, что сел - это в места не столь отдаленные, а в трамвае только присаживаются. И то и другое - неверно, более того, "присесть" - стилистическая ошибка, если имеется в виду не кратковременное сидение и не на краешке стула. Но миф этот живуч...

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень интересный анализ ситуации и в частности про сел/присел!)

Comment: Хотел после вашего ответа уточнить, что это было в метро, а там не принято сейчас сидеть рядом из-за коронавируса. Но зато это было двойное сидение в конце вагона с перегородкой, поэтому я и подумал, что может быть ничего. Да и вообще народу в вагоне было много и некоторые сидели рядом.

Comment: Трамвай у меня - условный городской транспорт. К вашему конкретно случаю отношения не имеет.

Comment: Да я и не запомнил, что вы трамвай упомянули. Естественно, ваше рассуждение относится к чему угодно. Я просто решил поделиться деталями. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Нормальная разговорная фраза. А что здесь может вызвать сомнение?

Не против - предикативное наречие в безличном предложении, имеющее синонимы: согласен, не прочь,  не возражаю. Это же не предлог, который требует присутствия существительного или местоимения.

А в связи с чем вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Да просто я ехал в метро и спросил у женщины так, а она как-то странно отреагировала, плечами, что ли, пожала, так что я не стал садиться. Я ещё подумал: может, я плохо сказал.